# Confusion about unjustified argument in solution to IMO 2018 algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-explanation, contest-math

The first algebra question in IMO 2018 is:

> Let $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ denote the set of all positive rational numbers. Determine all functions 
>   $f\colon \mathbb{Q}_{>0} \to \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ satisfying
>   $$f\left(x^2 f\left(y \right)^2 \right) = f\left(x \right)^2f\left(y \right)$$
>   for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}.$

In the first part of the solution they say:

> Take any $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}.$ By substituting $x = f\left(a \right) \dots$

This is where my issue is, the question asks you to prove for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$. Wouldn't substituting $x$ for $f\left(a \right)$ only be justified if $f$ was a bijective function?

Link: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2018SL.pdf

Comment: Can you link to the problem and the solution? Are you referring to the shortlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with the substitution.

The identity holds for all rational $x$. Since $f(a) $ is a rational number, we're allowed to set $ x = f(a)$.

We are saying "For all $a$, we have $x = f(a)$ and thus...

---

We are not saying that "For all $x$, there exists an $a$ such that $ x = f(a)$."
Yes, it might be that the image of $ f(a) $ isn't $\mathbb{Q}$.
(In particular, since the only solution is $f(x) = 1$.)

Comment: But you're asked to prove for all $x$ and $f(a)$ is only a subset of $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$. $f(a)$ and $x$ don't have the same restrictions.

Comment: Yes, you're asked to prove it for all $x$. That doesn't mean that you can't look at a subset of the rationals to gain some conclusions first, before looking at other things. How much familiarity do you have with functional equations?

Comment: I think that's the answer. I pretty much know nothing about functional equations.

Comment: @Seal: the "conclusion" of the proof does _not_ mention $\forall x$. It mentions $\forall a,b$. The idea is that the equation (*) applies for every $x,y$. It specifically then will also apply when $x = f(a)$ (where $a$ is arbitrary).

Comment: @WillieWong The question asks specifically to prove for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$

Comment: But $f(a)$ has more restrictions than $x$ has.

Comment: @Seal I'm going to try a different approach of explaining this. Set the above aside for the moment. How would you solve the functional equation $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(f(x)) = 0$? Can you describe some/all functions that satisfy this condition?

Comment: You could have $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: That's 1 possible solution. What others are there? How creative/crazy can we get?

Comment: Could you just define $f^2(x) = 0$.

Comment: To solve a functional equation means that we have to state it explicitly. E.g. we cannot say that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ is a solution, but we could say that $f(x) = a x$ is a solution.

Comment: You could also have $f(x) = 0 \cdot x$. I don't know any crazy definitions.

Comment: Here's one idea: $f(x) = 1$ for $ x \neq 1$, else $ f(1) = 0$? What else could we do?

Comment: You could do the same thing except $f(x) = a$ for $x \neq a$, else $f(a) = 0$ for any $a$,

Comment: I'm not quite sure what idea you're trying to make me come up with.

Comment: Suppose we are told that "Image of $f(x) $ is $ \{ 0, a \}$ with $ a \neq 0 $". Can you deduce what $f(a) $ must be equal to?

Comment: It must be zero?

Comment: How did you reach that conclusion? Can it be anything else?

Comment: I really don't know.

Comment: Alright, if so, I'd suggest reading up on the basics of functional equations, before jumping into IMO problems. One of the ideas is that you want to substitute in various values for $x$ and see what you can get. E.g. in my variant, what we can say is "If $f(a) = a$, then $ f(f(a)) = f(a) = a \neq 0 $. Hence we must have $f(a) = 0$ (as the only other possible option)"

Comment: It does not, because we've made no attempt to show that. As an aside, you'd have to be careful distinguishing between "$f(a) = a+1 \forall a$" and "$f(a) = a + 1$ for some $a$". E.g. Clearly $f(x) = x + 1 $ doesn't satisfy $f(f(x)) = 0 $, but we could have $ f(1) = 2, f (x) = 0 \, \forall x \neq 1$.